# Android Studio - native code compilation process does not show which files are compiling

Tags: c++, android-studio, gradle, compilation, native

Why android studio does not show full process of ndk compilation? I like to see which my c/cpp files are step by step processed by compilator and for which ABI. In "build" tab I only see warnings or errors, but not other processed files and for which ABI. Is there option to enable it? Many thanks. [image].

My android studio:

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1

ndk 24.0.8215888